# Windows Forms - how to exclude button from the whole set

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a `Windows Form` that contains only `buttons`. The final goal is to make a simple logic game I saw but for now the problem is that I want to perform different actions when my `New` button is clicked, but now it is part from all the `buttons` in the form so sometimes an action is performed on him too which should not happen. To make myself clear I have two screenshots :

[image]

So this is how I want it to be - I have a matrix - 3x3 (in this case, at the end it can be `NxN`). By clicking `New` I want to be able to do various things one of which is to make `N` buttons colored red. What happens now is sometimes my `New` button also get painted because I go over the buttons like this:

```
 foreach (Control c in this.Controls) 
                        {
                            if (c is Button)
                            {
                 ...
```

and thus sometimes `New` get selected too, so I end up with this:

[image]

What I'm thinking right now is just to perform check whenever I need in the code and exclude my `New` button explicitly but I don't think it's a good way cause I may end up with a code doing this thing in a lot of places in my program so what is the right solution in this case? If some code is needed please ask.

Comment: does your button has a different text than the rest of the buttons? if so could you just: if (ctl is Button) { if (ctl.text != "New) ... ?

Comment: @Andris That would technically work, but is the least elegant solution you could do. There are plenty of other ways to do this that would allow for this process to be able to be used in other situations as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite possibly the easiest solution is to put the Grid in its own Panel (`pnlGrid`). Put all of the buttons in there, then you could just do the following instead:

```
foreach (Control ctl in pnlGrid.Controls) { 
    if (ctl is Button) {
        // Do your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sound like the easiest at the moment

Comment: That will also make things a lot easier when you want to remove them. You just clear all controls out of the Panel, and won't have to worry about the New button getting removed.

Comment: Yeah, I think your suggestion is most close to the whole functionallity I need, really appreciated. Gonna accept it.

Comment: If you have any logic specific to how the buttons in that grid behave, it may even be worth making that as a completely separate User Control. You could take in the number of buttons to create in the constructor, and that way you can keep the logic separate from the Control that has the New Button.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try myself first and gonna ask again if there are problems :)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of looping through controls, add all the matrix buttons to a list, and have the `new` button separated:

```
private Button[] buttons;
private Button newButton;
```

Now you can add as many buttons as you'd like to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    buttons[i] = new Button();
    buttons[i].Text = "Button" + i;
    Controls.Add(buttons[i])
}
```

And lastly, your `New` button will loop through `buttons`:

```
private void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button b in buttons)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not trying to be cocky here, but imo this is better approach than krillgar's. No unnecessary panel required, it's all in one list. You can also edit the list easier than panel (for example, `foreach` loop is much simpler) and you can still remove all the buttons by simply removing the list. But use the method which works best for you :)

Comment: @Mahi You might get the [Populist](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/62/populist) Badge for getting more Upvotes than the accepted answer :-)

Comment: Yeah, I like your decision better in fact. But for my exact needs `Krillgar's` answer works best. That's the reason to choose his, but your idea is much more elegant I would say even though I'm just a beginner. I can appreciate a good idea :)

Comment: I highly doubt getting the badge. ^^ And use his solution then, just said my opinion. Hopefully you'll get the program running :)

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from the button class. Make your own button, use this control (that will have the same functionality that the parent one) for the set, and check for it when you iterate over the controls.

You could also use the Tag property for this pourpose, but I think that inherit will be more clear, adding semantic meaning to your code.